# Stanza SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate, stanford-nlp

I am trying to download the English models via `stanza.download('en')` I keep running to error below. I tried this in another laptop, and it worked just fine. What is causing the error below? How do I fix it?

Code:

```
import stanza
stanza.download('en')


SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='raw.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stanfordnlp/stanza-resources/master/resources_1.2.0.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

Try 1: Manually downloaded - Not working

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanza-resources into my local directory: `/Users/myusername/stanza_resources`

Try 2: not working/downloading

```
import requests
requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stanfordnlp/stanza-resources/master', verify=False)
```